# Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project openllet-protege

Tags: java, maven

I am installing https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/ but I get this error when launching the openllet.sh (I am on a mac, with JDK 17.02, I tried with JDK 16.02, but the issue persists)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project openllet-protege: Execution default-bundle of goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:bundle failed.: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]

There should be an issue in the POM.xml, but I can't figure out what is. The POM is available https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/blob/integration/pom.xml

**EDIT: I copy here the full output of the commands I used to find out more about the issue**

```
Lucas-MacBook-Pro:openllet-integration luca$ ./openllet.sh
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 3.5.2
Output file /Users/luca/Downloads/openllet-integration/module-jena/target/generated-sources/antlr3/openllet/query/sparqlowl/parser/antlr/SparqlOwlParser.java does not exist: must build /Users/luca/Downloads/openllet-integration/module-jena/src/main/antlr3/openllet/query/sparqlowl/parser/antlr/SparqlOwl.g
openllet/query/sparqlowl/parser/antlr/SparqlOwl.g
Output file /Users/luca/Downloads/openllet-integration/module-jena/target/generated-sources/antlr3/openllet/query/sparqlowl/parser/antlr/SparqlOwlTreeARQ.java does not exist: must build /Users/luca/Downloads/openllet-integration/module-jena/src/main/antlr3/openllet/query/sparqlowl/parser/antlr/SparqlOwlTreeARQ.g
openllet/query/sparqlowl/parser/antlr/SparqlOwlTreeARQ.g
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project openllet-protege: Execution default-bundle of goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:bundle failed.: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :openllet-protege
ERROR: Type 'openllet help' for usage.




And this is the output of mvn -X

Lucas-MacBook-Pro:openllet-integration luca$ mvn -X
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /Users/luca/apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /Users/luca/apache-maven-3.8.4/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/luca/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /Users/luca/apache-maven-3.8.4/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /Users/luca/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/luca/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/luca/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-parent:pom:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-functions:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-core:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-query:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-owlapi:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-jena:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-explanation:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-modularity:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-pellint:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-cli:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-profiler:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-examples:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-test:jar:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for snapshots (http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for codehaus.snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for apache.snapshots (http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for apache-snapshots (http://people.apache.org/maven-snapshot-repository).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for codehaus-snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org).
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1128753, ConflictMarker.markTime=402554, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=200, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=674836, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=351468, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=62, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=5230241, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=131, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=217408142, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=8995046}
[DEBUG] org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:4.1.0
[DEBUG]    org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:compile
[DEBUG]    biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bndlib:jar:4.1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.bundlerepository:jar:1.6.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.utils:jar:1.6.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:jar:4.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.7:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10:compile
[DEBUG]    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-apt:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xdoc:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm extension>org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm extension>org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm extension>org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:4.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bndlib:jar:4.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.bundlerepository:jar:1.6.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.utils:jar:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:jar:4.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: oro:oro:jar:2.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-apt:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xdoc:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-protege:bundle:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@531d72ca]]
[DEBUG] Created new class realm project>com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-protege:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Populating class realm project>com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-protege:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging bundle from ClassRealm[project>com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-protege:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-distribution:bundle:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@531d72ca]]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging bundle from ClassRealm[project>com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-protege:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[WARNING] The project com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-parent:pom:2.6.6-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Openllet :: Parent POM                                             [pom]
[INFO] Openllet :: Abstracts functions                                    [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Core                                                   [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Query                                                  [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: OWL API                                                [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Jena                                                   [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Explanation                                            [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Modularity                                             [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Pellint                                                [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: CLI                                                    [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Profiler                                               [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Examples                                               [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Tests                                                  [jar]
[INFO] Openllet :: Protege                                             [bundle]
[INFO] Openllet :: Distribution                                        [bundle]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Openllet :: Parent POM 2.6.6-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] Openllet :: Parent POM ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Abstracts functions .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Core ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Query .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: OWL API ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Jena ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Explanation ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Modularity ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Pellint ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: CLI .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Profiler ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Examples ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Tests .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Protege ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Openllet :: Distribution ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.543 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-23T09:59:37+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have more output of the issue...also how Maven has been called? Which version of Maven is used? Furthermore the pom files there is enforcer in 3.0.0-M1 why not 3.0.0... why so many deps for the cobertuara plugins??? Also remove the cobertura plugin.. Furhtmore why is such an old version of maven-bundle-plugin being used? There a lot of things which should be fixed... (using version ranges? Why?)...

Comment: I am using Apache Maven 3.8.4, which is the latest version. I did not create that POM file. I am using the one provided by the developers of openllet. Would it be possible for you to provide the amended file in the exact way you suggest?

Comment: I have now copied the full output I got from the commands

Comment: Launching mvn -e I got the following  `[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-.......`